# How to pass an array of fields from a jsp page to servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

> A sample program to fetch an array of namefields from a JSP form and fetch it on a servlet page. I couldn't figure out how to retrieve an array from the a form to the servlet. Kindly help me with this attempt.

### MyJSP page

```
<body>
<%!
   String name[]= new String[2];/*declares a string for storing two name fields*/
%>
<form action="page2">
<!--I need to send these name fields to the MyServlet page.so i used a String array to store both the values?-->

<%
  for(int i=1;i<=2;i++) {%>

  Username<%= i %> : <input type="text" name="<%=name%>">     
<% } %>
<input type="submit" value="ClickHere">
</form><!-- Upon submit goes to MyServlet page-->
</body>
```

### MyServlet Page

```
out.println("<body>");

String name[] = new String[2];
for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
{
 /*what should i enclose in getParameter(..?.) to obtain values from jsp*/
String name[i]=request.getParameter();//get the values from the form
}
out.println("</body>");
```

*Please suggest the improvements to be made in the code*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through all request parameters like so:

```
    Enumeration<String> en = request.getParameterNames();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        String paramName = en.nextElement();
        String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);            
    }
```

Comment: I tried executing this and it only fetched the first value from the form or did i do it wrong? And what changes should I have to make if I need to fetch an `int` instead?

Comment: It's because all of the request parameters have the same name. Try <input type="text" name="<%=name%>_<%=i%>">.

Comment: If you want an int, you would do:                                                                int number = Integer.parseInt(paramValue);